# How to talk about identity politics in mandarin?

Tags: mandarin

Talking about topics related to contemporary sexual identity and identity politics has been tricky in Mandarin... obviously a lot of this is specific to the American cultural milieu, and I haven't been able to find good translations. Any advice?

Some words that stick out:

heteronormative

heteronormativity

patriarchy

But I'm also curious if there are words specific to the Chinese context when discussing these topics?

Comment: 身份政治confirmed by http://zh.wordow.com/english/dictionary/identity%20politics: 身份政治 Politics focusing on the self-interest and perspectives of people in various groupings, such as race, gender, and religion. https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E6%96%87%E5%8C%96%E8%AA%8D%E5%90%8C （国际社会注意前进 Taiwan）article with 10 matches: https://socialisttw.wordpress.com/2015/12/08/%e6%89%93%e9%96%8b%e8%83%8c%e5%8c%85%ef%bc%9a%e8%ba%ab%e4%bb%bd%e6%94%bf%e6%b2%bb%e8%88%87%e5%b0%8d%e6%8a%97%e5%a3%93%e8%bf%ab%e7%9a%84%e9%ac%a5%e7%88%ad

Answer (score 5):

- Sexual orientation = **Sexual identity** = 性取向 or **性向**

~~~~~~~~~~~~

- Identity politic

> [identity politics](https://translate.google.ca/#en/zh-CN/identity%20politics)
>
> *Definitions of identity politics*
>
> *noun*
>
> *a tendency for people of a particular religion, race, social background, etc., to form exclusive political alliances, moving away from traditional broad-based party politics.*

Google translates "identity politics" as "身份政治" which is not a satisfactory translation to me.

With "政黨政治"(party politics), people can easily understand it means "*people making political choices or decisions base on their political party's direction*"

However, it is hard to connect "身份政治" with "*people making political choices or decisions base on their particular religion, race or social background*"

It would be much more accurate to translate it as "**群分政治**".

When people see this term, the idiom "物以類聚，人以**群分**" (things gather by type, people divide into groups) would come to their mind. They can easily put the two terms together and grasp the concept of "群分政治" means "*people of a particular religion, race, social background, etc., to form exclusive political alliances....*"

My other choice for "identity politics" is "**社群政治**" (society groups politics)

~~~~~~~~~~~~

Google's translations of [**heteronormativity**] as [**異性戀**] and [**patriarchy**] as [**父權制**] are acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

It is not American specific. It comes from Europe. The Frankfurt School and its cultural left movement prevails in the post-WWII era in Western world. The leftists try to destroy everything in the tradition of Western Civilisation. They identifies those minorities and describes them as victims. For example:

The black is minority and white is majority. Then they coins the word "white supremacy" and the black is the victim of white supremacy.

The female is minority and the male is majority. Then they coins the word "patriarchy" and the female is the victim of patriarchy.

The homosexual is minority and the heterosexual is majority. Then they coins the word "heteronormativity" and the homosexual is the victim heteronormativity.

These ideas can extends to Muslim vs Christianity or anything you can imagine.

In Chinese, it borrow the idea of hegemony of Marxism, i.e. you can say anything like that as 霸權.

When talking about white, it is 白人霸權.
When talking about male, it is 父系霸權 (patriarchy) or your may come across the word 父權 in some literature. 
When talking about heterosexual, it is 異性戀霸權 (heteronormativity).
When talking about Christianity, it is 基督教霸權.

霸權 is the word to use.

In mainland Chinese, there is no "politically correct" in Western sense.

Comment: 霸權 is too heavy a word, I prefer 沙文主义 https://www.google.ca/search?q=%E6%B2%99%E6%96%87%E4%B8%BB%E4%B9%89&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=mZ8oWY2wI6rcjwTknKSACQ

Comment: 霸權 is the terminology used very commonly in cultural leftist. They are talking about the power structure that they want to destroy. 沙文主義 is not quite the same.